# Creating a 2d vector from csv data

Tags: csv, vector, rust

I have a file ratings.csv which has rows such as:
Foo, 0, 1, 5, 3, -2, ...
Bar, 0, 4, 5, -3, ...
Each row starts with a customer name and has info about ratings afterwards. I want to create a 2d vector, in which each item is a row, and each item in that row is a user rating, stored as an `i32`. I'm also struggling to manipulate it such that the customer name isn't inside the subvector, as the subvectors should only contain `i32`.

I've tried the `read_to_string()` and `.split(",")` method but I can't find a way to transpose all the numbers to `i32` from `&str`.

It may be possible to transpose each value individually with the `.parse::<i32>()` method, but there is probably a more efficient way.

Comment: What is wrong with parsing each value individually? How do you define 'individually'? Please show code examples. I mean, every value is a string, so one way or another, each value has to be parsed from string to i32. There are of course libraries for that, but how many libraries are you willed to pull into your project? Do you want to do it without libraries, in std Rust? Is one library ok?

Comment: Is there a known number of values in every row?

Comment: Does each value mean something specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, parsing is done via specialized libraries, for security reasons.

You can of course do it by hand, especially if your input is as easy as CSV. But if you want to do it manually, then yes, you need to parse every single value.

I personally would use the [`csv`](https://docs.rs/csv) crate. It has built-in `serde` support, meaning, you can directly define the type you want to write the data into:

*ratings.csv:*

```
Foo,0,1,5,3,-2
Bar,0,4,5,-3,3
```

*main.rs:*

```rust
use std::{error::Error, fs::File};

type Rating = (String, Vec<i32>);

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open("ratings.csv")?;

    let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .from_reader(file);

    for result in reader.deserialize() {
        let record: Rating = result?;
        println!("{}: {:?}", record.0, record.1);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Foo: [0, 1, 5, 3, -2]
Bar: [0, 4, 5, -3, 3]
```